# I want to show last 4 products in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

There are many products in the database. but I only want to show the 4 most recently added products.

in the variable similar

views.py

```
def product_detail(request, category_slug, id):
category = Category.objects.all()
product = get_object_or_404(Product, category__slug = category_slug, id=id)
images = ProductImages.objects.filter(product_id=id)
similar = Product.objects.all().filter(category__slug=category_slug)
context = {
    'category': category,
    'product': product,
    'images': images,
    'similar': similar,
}

return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

Comment: How do you store in the database when a product was added?

Comment: Shall I share model.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```py
similar = Product.objects.all().filter(category__slug=category_slug).order_by('-creation_date')[:4]
```

Replace `creation_date` with the name of the field used to store the creation date of a `Product` instance

Comment: This worked. Thanks. so how can i make it randomly pick and display?

Comment: @sohretaga No problem. I'm not sure I understand your new question, but if you want to return products randomly use: `Product.objects.all().filter(category__slug=category_slug).order_by('?')[:4]`